# Admobs won't work in android and crashes application

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to ad admobs to my application but it ends up crashing it.  I had xml before but removed it because it won't work. I've tried so many things but now this is what I have ended up with.

```
    RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("**-***-***-***********/**************");
    rootLayout.addView(adView, 0);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I added this in front of setContentView in my Activities class. 
ive imported everything. am i missing something? I've declared everything in my MANIFEST file. and I've imported all the libraries.

```
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): Process: com.nonikhanna.Rainbox, PID: 5332
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.nonikhanna.Rainbox/com.nonikhanna.Rainbox.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.nonikhanna.Rainbox.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:26)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-02 03:08:51.922: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Add the stack trace from logcat if its crashing.

Comment: i added it, is this what you were asking?

Comment: Yup.  So what's on line 26?  YOu have a null pointer there.  Null pointers in onCreate almost always mean findViewById returned null, either because you didn't set a content view or because you used the wrong id.

Comment: I did that it doesn't crash, but the ads don't run still.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
AdView adView = new AdView(getApplicationContext());
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("***************");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
LinearLayout adView= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: it says there are duplicate adViews.
and The method addView(LinearLayout) is undefined for the type R.layout

Comment: Okay I got the answer.
I Looked at your code, and made a TextView in the xml file. 
I used it as a placeholder for ads. and it worked. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a background color on the AdView:

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/avwVXvBt_sM) if you still encounter problems

Answer (score 0):

Use this. In your code you are adding your add to view before it can load so you got NPE. Use this

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("**-***-***-***********/**************");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
rootLayout.addView(adView, 0);
```

Also check in your xml file that it is `RelativeLayout` and it id is the same as `RelativeLayout`